# Write permission error after installing application wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I have an issue in my current project . I am developing a wpf application and in which there is an xml file and need to be updated when some operation is carried out. But I am getting permission errors while  updating the xml file. Here is the code that i used.

```
    public void createxml()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            var outPutDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            var error = System.IO.Path.Combine(outPutDirectory, "foldername/filename.xml");
            string relsound = new Uri(error).LocalPath.Replace(@"\bin\Debug", "");
            writer = XmlWriter.Create(relsound, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteComment("This file is generated by the program.");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Category");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", "QuickformsForm");
            fill_subXML(o);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ae)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ae.ToString());
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  Create the XML file 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parm1"></param>
    public void fill_subXML(Int16 param1)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet subcat_SE = new DataSet();
            db_op.Open();
            subcat_SE = db_op.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, "SELECT query");
            db_op.Close();
            if (subcat_SE.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < subcat_SE.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Category");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", subcat_SE.Tables[0].Rows[k][0].ToString().Trim());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", subcat_SE.Tables[0].Rows[k][1].ToString().Trim());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Flag", "C");
                    DataSet dt_formmaster_SE = new DataSet();
                    db_op.Open();
                    dt_f1_SE = db_op.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, "select query");
                    db_op.Close();
                    if (dt_f1_SE .Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt_f1_SE .Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Form");
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", dt_f1_SE .Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString().Trim());
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", dt_f1_SE .Tables[0].Rows[j][1].ToString().Trim());
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("Flag", "F");
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                    }
                    fill_subXML(Convert.ToInt16(subcat_SE.Tables[0].Rows[k][0].ToString().Trim()));
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I set the full access to this file by right clicking the file and going to security tab, I am able to perform the action. Other wise I cannot. I tried to set it using code, but unfortunately none of my code works fine. So can anyone help me in this case. I tried some codes from stackoverflow and from other sites.
Regards,
Sivajith

Comment: Choose one of the [special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where your application has write access to edit your XML file, e.g LocalApplicationData.

Comment: I am using a folder in my application itself. Is that causes error?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Write permissions are limited in the application directory. You should be fine if you use one of the directories where your app is _supposed_ to write. But I didn't check your code! Might be there is an additional error. Start with using the application data directory and you will see..